# Nginx rewrite: remove ? after filename.php

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Here's my current nginx site config:

```
server {
server_name DOMAIN;
access_log /srv/www/DOMAIN/logs/access.log;
error_log /srv/www/DOMAIN/logs/error.log;
root /srv/www/DOMAIN/public_html;

location / {
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {  return 302 /$1;  }
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\.php($|\?)) {  return 302 /$1?$args;  }
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}

}
```

So the problem I can't seem to figure out is that when I access a web page like "mydomain.com/filename.php" the URL will be written to "mydomain.com/filename?". What would I edit to make to remove the end "?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line adds a `?` to the end of any externally presented URI ending with `.php`:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\.php($|\?)) {  return 302 /$1?$args;  }`.
```

A quick fix would be to use `$is_args` instead of the `?`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_is_args) for details.